# Extra arguments at position

Tags: swiftui

I have a struct and I keep getting a extra arguments at positions error after I have added a decoder.I get the error on the return line. Any help would be appreciated. This issue only started happening as soon as I added the decoder to the struct so I am guesing now when I try to create a new instance of an Absence I need to do it slightly differently? I am quite new to SwiftUI Here is the code:

````
struct Absence: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: Int
    var userId: Int
    var start: Date
    var end: Date
    var active: Bool
    var modifiedBy: Int
    var modified: Date
    
    // Custom initializer to handle date conversion
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        userId = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .userId)
        active = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .active)
        modifiedBy = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .modifiedBy)
        
        // Custom date decoding
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy" // Modify the date format as needed
        
        if let startDateString = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .start),
           let startDate = dateFormatter.date(from: startDateString) {
            start = startDate
        } else {
            start = Date() // Provide a default date if decoding fails
        }
        
        if let endDateString = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .end),
           let endDate = dateFormatter.date(from: endDateString) {
            end = endDate
        } else {
            end = Date() // Provide a default date if decoding fails
        }
        
        if let modifiedString = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .modified),
           let modifiedDate = dateFormatter.date(from: modifiedString) {
            modified = modifiedDate
        } else {
            modified = Date() // Provide a default date if decoding fails
        }
    }
    
    static func sampleData() -> Absence {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy" // Modify the date format as needed

        let startString = "01/01/2021"
        let endString = "01/02/2021"
        let modifiedString = "01/03/2021" // Change this to the appropriate date string

        let startDate = dateFormatter.date(from: startString) ?? Date()
        let endDate = dateFormatter.date(from: endString) ?? Date()
        let modifiedDate = dateFormatter.date(from: modifiedString) ?? Date()

        return Absence(id: 1, userId: 1, start: startDate, end: endDate, active: true, modifiedBy: 1, modified: modifiedDate)
    }}
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Currently your `init(...)` only takes a single `Decoder` parameter, but you are calling `Absence(id: 1, ...)`
with many more parameters, that is the reason for the error.

So add another `init(...)` with the parameters you desire, such as:

```
 init(id: Int, userId: Int, start: Date, end: Date, active: Bool, modifiedBy: Int, modified: Date) {
     self.id = id
     self.userId = userId
     self.start = start
     self.end = end
     self.active = active
     self.modifiedBy = modifiedBy
     self.modified = modified
 }
```

Note that, if you did not have `init(from decoder: Decoder) ...` you would automatically
get a memberwise initializer, **if** you have not defined any other custom initializers. See also [the docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/initialization#Memberwise-Initializers-for-Structure-Types)

Comment: did my answer not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Swift struct's get an initializer from compiler by default if you haven't defined a initializer yourself. This is called **memberwise initializer**. Since, you have added your own decoder to initialize Absence, it loses the **memberwise initializer**. So you are getting the error.

You can add the decoder in an extension so that you will still keep the memberwise initializer for Absence. Then, you can still initialize like Absence(id: 1, userId: 12,...) for example.

```
struct Absence: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: Int
    var userId: Int
    var start: Date
    var end: Date
    var active: Bool
    var modifiedBy: Int
    var modified: Date
}

extension Absence {
    ---- your decoder code here ----
}
```